# Why pressing of "Tab" key emits only QEvent::ShortcutOverride event?

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, qitemdelegate, qevent

## Background

I've made a custom widget with `QLineEdit` and several `QPushButtons` to use it with custom item delegate:

```
class LineEditor : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit LineEditor(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);

        layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        layout()->setSpacing(0);

        QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
        layout()->addWidget(edit);
        layout()->addWidget(new QPushButton(this));
        layout()->addWidget(new QPushButton(this));

        setFocusProxy(edit);
    }
};

class PropertyDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
public:
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
        return new LineEditor(parent);
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
            qDebug() << "KeyPress";
        }
        if (event->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride) {
            qDebug() << "ShortcutOverride";
        }

        return QItemDelegate::eventFilter(object, event);
    }
};
```

I'm going to bind them with `QListView` and `QStandardItemModel` like this:

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
model->appendRow(new QStandardItem("1"));
model->appendRow(new QStandardItem("2"));
model->appendRow(new QStandardItem("3"));

QListView w;
w.setItemDelegate(new PropertyDelegate);
w.setModel(model);
w.show();
```

## Question

Why in the `PropertyDelegate::eventFilter` when `Tab` key is pressed there is only `QEvent::ShortcutOverride` event, but pressing of any other key emits both `QEvent::ShortcutOverride` and `QEvent::KeyPress` events?

**UPD:** I want to implement the moving between lines by pressing `Tab` and `Backtab` like with standard widgets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, finally I've done some research about that.

## Explanation

When a view calls `createEditor` function of delegate it also installs the delegate event filter to editor.

```
QWidget *QAbstractItemViewPrivate::editor(const QModelIndex &index,
                                          const QStyleOptionViewItem &options)
{
    Q_Q(QAbstractItemView);
    QWidget *w = editorForIndex(index).widget.data();
    if (!w) {
        QAbstractItemDelegate *delegate = delegateForIndex(index);
        if (!delegate)
            return 0;
        w = delegate->createEditor(viewport, options, index);
        if (w) {
            w->installEventFilter(delegate);

    ......
}
```

However the delegate can catch only events of editor widget, but not events of its children. When the `Tab` key is pressed the `QWidget::event` function is called, it uses it to change focus to another widget:

```
bool QWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
    ......

    switch (event->type()) {
        ......
        case QEvent::KeyPress: {
        QKeyEvent *k = (QKeyEvent *)event;
        bool res = false;
        if (!(k->modifiers() & (Qt::ControlModifier | Qt::AltModifier))) {  //### Add MetaModifier?
            if (k->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab
                || (k->key() == Qt::Key_Tab && (k->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier)))
                res = focusNextPrevChild(false);
            else if (k->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
                res = focusNextPrevChild(true);
            if (res)
                break;
        }

        ......
    }

    ......
}
```

Accordingly in my case the focus is set to next `QPushButton` after `QLineEdit` and event isn't propagated to the parent (`LineEditor`).

## Solving

The right way to solve the problem is like `QSpinBox` does it. Because it is also has `QLineEdit`. In constructor of widget it sets focus proxy for line edit:

```
edit->setFocusProxy(this);
```

So all of focus events will reach the main widget. Also the `focusPolicy` property must be set because it's `NoFocus` by default:

```
setFocusPolicy(Qt::WheelFocus);
```

All we need to do in this moment it is to propagate necessary events to `QLineEdit` from main widget like this:

```
bool LineEditor::event(QEvent *e)
{
    switch(e->type())
    {
    case QEvent::ShortcutOverride:
        if(m_lineEdit->event(e))
            return true;
        break;

    case QEvent::InputMethod:
        return m_lineEdit->event(e);

    default:
        break;
    }

    return QWidget::event(e);
}

void LineEditor::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    m_lineEdit->event(e);
}

void LineEditor::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->button() != Qt::LeftButton)
        return;

    e->ignore();
}

void LineEditor::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    e->accept();
}

void LineEditor::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    m_lineEdit->event(e);
    QWidget::focusInEvent(e);
}

void LineEditor::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    m_lineEdit->event(e);
    QWidget::focusOutEvent(e);
}
```

This should be enough.

## Tricky

As it's said above the delegate can't catch events of editor's children. So to make editor's behavior like "native" I have to duplicate events from children to editor.

`LineEditor` installs event filter to `QLineEdit` in constructor:

```
edit->installEventFilter(this);
```

Implementation of filter looks like this:

```
bool LineEditor::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab || keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab)
        {
            QApplication::postEvent(this, new QKeyEvent(keyEvent->type(), keyEvent->key(), keyEvent->modifiers()));
            // Filter this event because the editor will be closed anyway
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if(event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
    {
        QFocusEvent* focusEvent = static_cast<QFocusEvent *>(event);
        QApplication::postEvent(this, new QFocusEvent(focusEvent->type(), focusEvent->reason()));

        // Don't filter because focus can be changed internally in editor
        return false;
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

It's also possible to use `qApp->notify(this, event)` for `QKeyEvent` instead of `QApplication::postEvent` because we filter this events anyway. But it's not possible for `QFocusEvent` because `notify` will redirect the event and it will not reach a child.

Note that the standard (`QItemDelegate` or `QStyledItemDelegate`) delegate will care about situation when focus is changed internally by itself:

```
if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut || (event->type() == QEvent::Hide && editor->isWindow())) {
        //the Hide event will take care of he editors that are in fact complete dialogs
        if (!editor->isActiveWindow() || (QApplication::focusWidget() != editor)) {
            QWidget *w = QApplication::focusWidget();
            while (w) { // don't worry about focus changes internally in the editor
                if (w == editor)
                    return false;
                w = w->parentWidget();
            }

    ......
```