# How to close an editor created by a custom QItemDelegate::createEditor()

Tags: c++, qt, qitemdelegate, qabstractitemview

I have created a custom item delegate which lets users edit a list of file paths:

[image: screenshot]

I have achieved this through a custom class DirEdit. Now the selected path is commited and the editor is closed when the user presses enter, but I would like to add two cases where the editor should be closed without the user having to press enter:

1. When the user selects a file by activating a combo box entry(by clicking or pressing return)
2. When the user selects a file by clicking the "ellipsis" tool button.

I have been exprimenting with clearFocus() and other methods, but nothing seems to work. Below is a complete example:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class DirEdit : public QWidget
{
    QLineEdit* lineEdit=nullptr;
public:
    DirEdit(QWidget* parent=nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        new QHBoxLayout(this);
        layout()->setMargin(0);
        layout()->addWidget(lineEdit=new QLineEdit(this));

        QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(this);

        auto model = new QDirModel(completer);
        model->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
        completer->setModel(model);

        lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
        connect(completer, static_cast<void (QCompleter::*)(const QString&)>(&QCompleter::activated), [this](const QString& text)
            {
// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> TODO: Make the editor close here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            });

        QToolButton* dotDotDot;
        layout()->addWidget(dotDotDot=new QToolButton(this));
        dotDotDot->setText("...");
        connect(dotDotDot, &QToolButton::clicked, this, [this]()
            {
                QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(window(), "Select Directory", lineEdit->text());
                if(dir!="")
                {
                    lineEdit->setText(dir);
// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> TODO: Make the editor close here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                }
            });
        setFocusProxy(lineEdit);
    }
    void setPath(const QString& path)
    {
        lineEdit->setText(path);
    }
    QString path()const
    {
        return lineEdit->text();
    }
};

class MyDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        return new DirEdit(parent);
    }

    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex &)const
    {
        editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
    }

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QVariant value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole);

        if (DirEdit *dirEdit = dynamic_cast<DirEdit *>(editor))
            dirEdit->setPath(value.toString());
    }

    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        if (DirEdit *dirEdit = dynamic_cast<DirEdit *>(editor))
            model->setData(index, dirEdit->path());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QListWidget listWidget;

    listWidget.setItemDelegate(new MyDelegate);

    listWidget.addItem(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation));
    listWidget.addItem(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::MusicLocation));
    listWidget.addItem(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation));
    listWidget.addItem(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation));

    for (int i = 0; i<listWidget.count(); i++)
        listWidget.item(i)->setFlags(listWidget.item(0)->flags()|Qt::ItemIsEditable);

    listWidget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Maybe `QAbstractItemView::closePersistentEditor()` can help?

Comment: @vahancho I don't think so since it isn't a persistent editor(as created by QAbstractItemView::openPersistentEditor())

Comment: Hm, I think you need to close the `QCompleter::popup()`? What about calling `completer->popup()->close()`?

Comment: The popup closes when I click an item or presses enter. The problem is that the line edit keeps the focus and remains open.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Replace the TODOs with

```
QApplication::postEvent(this, new QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier));
```

## Motivation:

I found the key to the answer here: [Why pressing of "Tab" key emits only QEvent::ShortcutOverride event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145522/why-pressing-of-tab-key-emits-only-qeventshortcutoverride-event)

There is an event filter in place looking for certain events so I only have to trigger one of those:

```
// Edited for brevity.
bool QItemDelegate::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    QWidget *editor = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(object);

    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        switch (static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event)->key()) {
        case Qt::Key_Enter:
        case Qt::Key_Return:
            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "_q_commitDataAndCloseEditor",
                                      Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QWidget*, editor));
            return false;
    }
}
```

I tried first posting a FocusOut event like @fasked suggests in that other post, but that didn't work in this case

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by `setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex())`.

```cpp
QTreeView *tree;
// ...
// ...
QObject::connect(outsideButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [tree](){
    tree->setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex());
});
```